# How to get custom logging function with level-specific macros to handle formatted printing

Tags: c

cd_log.h:

```c
#ifndef CONQUER_DOCKER_CD_LOG_H
#define CONQUER_DOCKER_CD_LOG_H

#define CD_CURRENT_LOG_LEVEL CD_LOG_INFO_LEVEL

#define CD_LOG_DEBUG(message) cd_log(&CD_LOG_DEBUG_LEVEL, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, message)
#define CD_LOG_INFO(message) cd_log(&CD_LOG_INFO_LEVEL, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, message)
#define CD_LOG_WARNING(message) cd_log(&CD_LOG_WARNING_LEVEL, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, message)
#define CD_LOG_ERROR(message) cd_log(&CD_LOG_ERROR_LEVEL, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, message)

/**
 * log level
 */
typedef struct CDLogLevel {
    const char level;
    /**
     * level name
     */
    const char *name;
} CDLogLevel;

/**
 * log level
 */
extern const CDLogLevel CD_LOG_DEBUG_LEVEL;
extern const CDLogLevel CD_LOG_INFO_LEVEL;
extern const CDLogLevel CD_LOG_WARNING_LEVEL;
extern const CDLogLevel CD_LOG_ERROR_LEVEL;

/**
 * print log
 */
void cd_log(
        const CDLogLevel *logLevel, const char *fileName, const char *functionName, int line,
        const char *message
);

#endif //CONQUER_DOCKER_CD_LOG_H
```

c_log.c

```c
#include "include/cd_log.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const CDLogLevel CD_LOG_DEBUG_LEVEL = {0, "DEBUG"};
const CDLogLevel CD_LOG_INFO_LEVEL = {1, "INFO"};
const CDLogLevel CD_LOG_WARNING_LEVEL = {2, "WARNING"};
const CDLogLevel CD_LOG_ERROR_LEVEL = {3, "ERROR"};

static const char *coloring(const CDLogLevel *logLevel) {
    size_t strLength = strlen(logLevel->name);
    size_t newStrLen = strLength + 16;
    char *newStr = malloc(newStrLen);
    memset(newStr, 0, newStrLen);

    if (logLevel->level == CD_LOG_DEBUG_LEVEL.level) {
        snprintf(newStr, newStrLen, "\033[34m%s\033[0m", logLevel->name);
    } else if (logLevel->level == CD_LOG_INFO_LEVEL.level) {
        snprintf(newStr, newStrLen, "\033[32m%s\033[0m", logLevel->name);
    } else if (logLevel->level == CD_LOG_WARNING_LEVEL.level) {
        snprintf(newStr, newStrLen, "\033[33m%s\033[0m", logLevel->name);
    } else if (logLevel->level == CD_LOG_ERROR_LEVEL.level) {
        snprintf(newStr, newStrLen, "\033[31m%s\033[0m", logLevel->name);
    } else {
        free(newStr);
        return logLevel->name;
    }
    return newStr;
}

void cd_log(const CDLogLevel *logLevel, const char *fileName, const char *functionName, int line, const char *message) {
    if (logLevel->level < CD_CURRENT_LOG_LEVEL.level) {
        return;
    }
    time_t currentTime = time(NULL);
    char timerStr[20];
    strftime((char *) &timerStr, 20, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(&currentTime));

    if (isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)) {
        const char *levelStr = coloring(logLevel);
        fprintf(stdout, "%s [%-15s] %-80s %s %5d: %s\n",
                (char *) &timerStr, levelStr, fileName, functionName, line, message);
        free((void *) levelStr);
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s [%-7s] %-80s %s %5d: %s\n",
                (char *) &timerStr, logLevel->name, fileName, functionName, line, message);
    }
}
```

It is fine to simply print the string in this way.

```c
CD_LOG_INFO("Hello World");
```

```
2021-09-22 22:26:02 [INFO  ] /home/aszswaz/project/CLionProjects/conquer-docker/src/main.c                    main     8: Hello World
```

To realize the splicing of multiple parameters, you need to do this:

```c
char string[BUFSIZ];
snprintf(string, BUFSIZ, "value01: %s, value02: %d", "demo", 101);
CD_LOG_INFO(string);
memset(string, 0, BUFSIZ);
```

```
2021-09-22 22:31:00 [INFO  ] /home/aszswaz/project/CLionProjects/conquer-docker/src/main.c                    main    10: value01: demo, value02: 101
```

This is too much trouble. I want to integrate the snprintf function into the cd_log function. The most important thing is that the parameter length of snprintf is not fixed. I don't want to change this.

I want to change it like this, but I don't know how to do it.

```c
CD_LOG_INFO("value01: %s, value02: %s, value03: %d" , "demo01", "demo2", 100);
```

Comment: Write another function, say, `CD_LOG_INFO_F`, that does what you want?

Comment: Or, just model `CD_LOG_INFO` on the way `printf` does things.  printf only requires the first parameter; the rest are optional.

Comment: If this was easily solvable, the function `printf` would not be in use

Comment: If you didn't know about it, there's a whole Stack Exchange site called [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) that specializes in this kind of thing.  You might get more attention on improving your code over there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your log function to be variadic by adding `...` to the end of the parameter list.  Then inside of the function, print the fixed parts of the log first followed by the variadic part using `vfprintf`

```
void cd_log(const CDLogLevel *logLevel, const char *fileName, 
            const char *functionName, int line, const char *message, ...) 
{
    if (logLevel->level < CD_CURRENT_LOG_LEVEL.level) {
        return;
    }
    time_t currentTime = time(NULL);
    char timerStr[20];
    // pass timerStr directly without cast
    strftime(timerStr, 20, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(&currentTime));

    // print header part of line
    if (isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)) {
        const char *levelStr = coloring(logLevel);
        // pass timerStr directly without cast
        fprintf(stdout, "%s [%-15s] %-80s %s %5d: ",
                timerStr, levelStr, fileName, functionName, line);
        free(levelStr);   // no cast needed here
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s [%-7s] %-80s %s %5d: ",
                timerStr, logLevel->name, fileName, functionName, line);
    }

    // print variadic part
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, message)
    vfprintf(stdout, message, args);
    va_end(args);

    // print trailing newline
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
}
```

Then in the header, use variadic macros for the specific log levels:

```
#define CD_LOG_DEBUG(...) cd_log(&CD_LOG_DEBUG_LEVEL, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
#define CD_LOG_INFO(...) cd_log(&CD_LOG_INFO_LEVEL, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
#define CD_LOG_WARNING(...) cd_log(&CD_LOG_WARNING_LEVEL, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
#define CD_LOG_ERROR(...) cd_log(&CD_LOG_ERROR_LEVEL, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Note that we're not explicitly calling out the `message` parameter here.  The reason for this is if the message has no format specifiers, meaning no extra arguments, using the `__VA_ARGS__` macro would generate an error.

Also, your `coloring` function is returning allocated memory in most cases but a static string in this case:

```
} else {
    free(newStr);
    return logLevel->name;
}
```

If you were to attempt to `free` this your program would likely crash.  So just always use the allocated memory and copy the string in.

```
} else {
    strcpy(newStr, logLevel->name);
}
```

Comment: IMHO, even better to define `vcd_log()`, replacing `cd_log()`'s variadic part with a `va_list` parameter, and define the variadic `cd_log()` as a wrapper.